# error C2059: syntax error : '='

Tags: visual-studio

I keep getting the same two syntax errors and I can't figure out why. can someone please help me figure out what is wrong and why I keep getting these syntax errors

```
shipping.c<61> : error C2059: syntax error : '='
shipping.c<70> : error C2059: syntax error : '='
```

This is the code that my errors are in:

/* DO NOT COPY */

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <math.h> 
#define PI = 3.14159
#define PACKING_DENSITY = 0.59
```

/* Function prototype */

```
double bearing(double radius, double diameter);

double actual_weight(double density, double pound);

int shipping_weight(double actualWeight, double roundingFix);

double cost_per_box(int shippingWeight, double shippingRate);


int
main(void)
{
```

/* giving variables names */

```
double width;
double height;
double depth;
double diameter;
double density;
double shippingRate;
double costPerBox;
double radius;
```

/* calling for the variables */

```
printf("Enter width %d\n");
scanf("%lf", &width);
printf("Enter height %d\n");
scanf("%lf", &height);
printf("Enter depth %d\n");
scanf("%lf", &depth);
printf("Enter diameter %d\n");
scanf("%lf", &diameter);
printf("Enter density %d\n");
scanf("%lf", &density);
printf("Enter shipping rate %d\n");
scanf("%lf", &shippingRate);
```

/* Returning answers */

```
printf("Bearings = %f\n", bearing);
printf("Shipping weight = %f\n", shipping_weight);
printf("Shipping cost per box = %f\n", cost_per_box);

return(0);

}
```

/* calculations for bearing */

```
double
bearing(double radius, double diameter)
{   
radius = diameter / 2;

return((4 / 3) * pow(radius, 3) *PI);
}
```

/* calculations for actual weight */

```
double 
actual_weight(double density, double pound)
{
pound = 2.20464; /* <=conversion */

return(density * PACKING_DENSITY * pound); 

}
```

/* calculations for shipping weight */

```
int
shipping_weight(double actualWeight, double roundingFix)
{
roundingFix = .9;

return(actualWeight + roundingFix);

}
```

/* calculations for cost per box */

```
double 
cost_per_box(int shippingWeight, double shippingRate)
{

return(shippingWeight * shippingRate);

}
```

Comment: You don't put a "=" for defining macros. Simply do, `#define PI 3.14159` and woosh....all errors gone.

Answer (score 0):

You defined your `PI` macro as

```
#define PI = 3.14159
```

which means that every occurence of `PI` will be replaced by `= 3.14159`. For example this

```
return((4 / 3) * pow(radius, 3) *PI);
```

will turn into this

```
return((4 / 3) * pow(radius, 3) * = 3.14159);
```

This just does not make any sense. (Note that tokens do not concatenate in this case, i.e. `*` followed by `=` does not form a `*=` operator).

Why did you include that `=` into the replacement text for `PI`? The same question applies to

```
#define PACKING_DENSITY = 0.59
```

What is that `=` doing there?